# No suitable constructor found on SimpleSpannerRepository - SpringBoot 3 with Native image

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Im facing this issue in my SpringBoot3 application executed using GraalVm. Im trying to connect the application to a Spanner emulator. TppRepository is an interface that extends SpannerRepository. The Build is successful, but fails during runtime

TppRespository

```
@Repository
public interface TppRepository extends SpannerRepository<Tpp, String> {

    Iterable<Tpp> findAll();

    Optional<Tpp> findByTppId(String tppId);

}
```

error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tppController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tppService': Error creating bean with name 'tppServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tppRepository': Error creating bean with name 'tppRepository': No suitable constructor found on class com.google.cloud.spring.data.spanner.repository.support.SimpleSpannerRepository to match the given arguments: com.google.cloud.spring.data.spanner.core.SpannerTemplate, java.lang.Class. Make sure you implement a constructor taking these
```

I tried putting Runtime Hint and importing it in the SpringBootApplication class

```
static class MyRuntimeHints implements RuntimeHintsRegistrar {

        @Override
        public void registerHints(RuntimeHints hints, ClassLoader classLoader) {
            hints.reflection()
                    .registerConstructor(
                            SimpleSpannerRepository.class.getConstructors()[0], ExecutableMode.INVOKE);
        }
    }
```

Am i doing anything wrong with the hints?

Comment: You can use `-H:+PrintUniverse` to check if the constructor you need gets compiled into the image (look under "compiled methods" section). E.g. I'm not sure how constructors are ordered inside the array, it might be that constructor #0 is not the one you need